# Type Mismatch Error when Passing Child Type to Subroutine accepting Parent Type VBA

Tags: excel, vba, interface, runtime-error

### Context

I have a parent interface, `IParent`,

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoParentStuff()
End Sub
```

a child interface implementing `IParent`, `IChild`,

```
Option Explicit

Implements IParent

Private Sub IParent_DoParentStuff()
End Sub

Public Sub DoParentStuff()
End Sub
```

and a concrete implementation of `IChild`, `CStandardChild`.

```
Option Explicit

Implements IChild

Private Sub IChild_DoParentStuff()
End Sub

Public Sub DoParentStuff()
  IChild_DoParentStuff
End Sub
```

I then created a module that passes a variable of type `IChild` to a subroutine with one parameter of type `IParent`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test(ByRef parent As IParent)
  parent.DoParentStuff
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
  Dim child As IChild
  
  Set child = New CStandardChild
  
  Test child
End Sub
```

I can compile the VBA project without error. But, when I run `Main`, I get a run-time error

> Run-time error '13':
>
> Type mismatch

The debugger points to the code `Test child`.

### Question

Why am I getting a run-time, type-mismatch error? How can I pass `child` to `Test()` without getting this error?

### What I've Tried

I've looked into casting `IChild` to `IParent`. However, I'm not using `VB.NET`, so, I don't have access to `DirectCast` and `CType`. In saying this, if I've implemented `IParent` and `IChild` appropriately, I didn't think a cast is necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you just looking for a way to cast to an `IParent` in VBA?  Just declare `Dim foo As IParent: Set foo = child`

Comment: Hi @Comintern, I'm trying to pass `child` to `Test()` without receiving a `Type mismatch` error. However, your comment may be a way to do it, I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it looks like you're trying to extend `IParent` with `IChild` members. You can't do that in VBA - it would be awesome, but it's part of what makes .NET a more flexible framework to work with.

To take a C# analogy - this is what I think you're trying to do (and is illegal in VBA):

```
interface IFoo { void DoSomething() }
interface IBar : IFoo { void DoStuff() } // inherits members of IFoo
```

If you need `CStandardChild` to be accessible through both `IParent` and `IChild` interfaces, you need both `Implements` statements in that class:

```
Option Explicit
Implements IChild
Implements IParent

'implement members of both interfaces...
```

Then you can pass an instance of that class and "cast" it to either interface.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know.